# QT 5.1.1 - Problems with setting urlQuery in Post Request

Tags: c++, qt, post, qt5

I'm working on porting over some network code from QT 4.8.4 to 5.1.1 and seem to have run into a problem that I can't quite figure out.

```
QUrl postURL = QUrl("https://www.mywebsite/api");

QUrlQuery * reqParams = new QUrlQuery();
reqParams->addQueryItem("realEmail", email_lineEdit->text());
reqParams->addQueryItem("password", password_lineEdit->text());
reqParams->addQueryItem("confirmPassword", passConfirm_lineEdit->text());
reqParams->addQueryItem("firstName", firstName_lineEdit->text());
reqParams->addQueryItem("lastName", lastName_lineEdit->text());
reqParams->addQueryItem("termsAccepted", "1");

postURL.setQuery(reqParams);

QNetworkRequest netReq(postURL);
netReq.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
config.setProtocol(QSsl::SslV3);
netReq.setSslConfiguration(config);

netReply = netManager->post(netReq);
```

Compiling this gives me two errors. Firstly, `'QNetworkAccessManager::post' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments` I'm not sure how to resolve this since I dont need to add any post data, its all included in the QUrlQuery as I was under the impression this was the correct way of doing it.

My second error, `'void QUrl::setQuery(const QString &,QUrl::ParsingMode)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QUrlQuery *' to 'const QString &'` This one has me just as confused. I know there to be an overload of setQuery that takes a QUrlQuery * so the fact that with one parameter its assuming the 2 parameter version makes little to no sense to me.

If anyone can shed light on both, or either, matter I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't want to do a HTTP POST as you don't want to send any data in the body of the request. You want to execute a HTTP GET request. For that you should call manager.get:

```
netReply = manager->get(netReq);
```

If you want to execute a HTTP POST request with empty body, then you have to specify empty byte array like this:

```
QByteArray empty;
netReply = manager->post(netReq, empty);
```

You need to pass a reference (not a pointer) to qUrl::setQuery. E.g. do this:

```
QUrlQuery reqParams;
reqParams.addQueryItem("realEmail", email_lineEdit->text());
...
postURL.setQuery(reqParams);
```